# HazelcastJsonValue in the model class

Tags: java, hazelcast

How to use HazelcastJsonValue in the model class

```
public class User implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private HazelcastJsonValue value;
```

In the IMap I'm inserting the value some thing like this

```
map.put(i,new User(obj.getId,obj.getName,new HazelcastJsonValue(value.toString)));
```

Its throwing Serialization Exception for HazelcastJsonValue

How to resolve this isssue..?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 approaches to resolve this:

1. you either move away from using `HazelcastJsonValue` in the model class, so you use the string representation of the json, or anything that is serializable.
2. you have to override the serialization method of this class by adding a `readObject()` and a `writeObject()` method, and use a serializable representation of the json value while writing (string is a straightforward choice), and parse it while reading. Example (this just ran successfully for me):

```java
package com.hazelcast.client.pncounter;

import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastJsonValue;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Whatever {
    
    static class User implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private HazelcastJsonValue value;

        public User(String id, String name, HazelcastJsonValue value) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
        
        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)
                throws IOException {
            out.writeObject(id);
            out.writeObject(name);
            out.writeObject(value.toString());
        }
        
        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
                throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            id = (String) in.readObject();
            name = (String) in.readObject();
            value = new HazelcastJsonValue((String) in.readObject());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        out.writeObject(new User("1", "name", new HazelcastJsonValue("{}")));
        out.flush();
        
        User user = (User) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())).readObject();
    }
}
```

Please refer to the [Java SE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for details about customizing the serialization process.